# Fuse replacement

Tags: amperage

I’m trying to replace a fuse on my aerobic wastewater treatment system control box. The fuse has the following inscriptions embedded on one end. Also, it is a glass or clear fuse with metal ends. ET5AL250v. I have attempted to locate this fuse without success and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably a T2.5AL250V, at a guess. Maybe a T12.5AL250V. In any case, just look around for the 5AL250V portion and look at pictures. I think you'll find it.

Comment: As @jonk pointed out, the fuse ratings are: 5 Ampers, 250 Volts. Given the abundance of such fuses on the market, you simply need to find a fuse with such ratings having the physical dimensions that will fit in your fuse holder.

Comment: If you include a picture, we can also see if it's fast or slow blowing. That matters too.

Answer (score 0):

This type of fuse is typically in a fuse holder. Look for the fuse holder.

https://www.wiringproducts.com/inline-heavy-duty-glass-fuse-holder-35-amp-10-ga.html

Comment: I think the OP has found the fuse as they have read the details.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a 5A 250V 5x20mm **slow-blow** fuse, similar to Bel Fuse  [5ET 5-R](https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-5et-5etp-series.pdf).

That one has decent interrupting capacity for home use (150A) and is slow blow. If you replace a slow blow type with a fast blow you'll have protection but will almost surely suffer from nuisance blowing, likely from the first time power is applied.